# I want the input to be not case sensitive

Tags: java

For example, when the user types "September", "SEPTEMBER", "september", "SepTEMber" or anyhow it will be a valid entry as long as the letters are correct. And what is a neater way to write this code( the part where I used "||".)?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Compare {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s1 = getInput("Enter a month ");
        if(s1.equals("February")) {
            System.out.println("It's time to go to the Disneyland !");
            String s2 = getInput("Enter another month: ");
            if(s2.equals("February")) {
                System.out.println("You already won a Disneyland ticket! Try       another month.");
                String s3 = getInput("Enter another month: ");
                  if(s3.equals("January") || 
                     s3.equals("March") || 
                     s3.equals("April") || 
                     s3.equals("July") || 
                     s3.equals("May") || 
                     s3.equals("September") || 
                     s3.equals("October") || 
                     s3.equals("November") || 
                     s3.equals("Aguest") || 
                     s3.equals("July") || 
                     s3.equals("December")) {
                     System.out.println("You will go to Paris");
                  }else {
                     String s4 = getInput("Leave your name and phone number. We will call you back. ");
                     System.out.println("Thanks for visiting! Goodbye !");
                   }    
              }
         }
     }
    private static String getInput(String prompt) {
        BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.print(prompt);
        System.out.flush();

        try {
            return stdin.readLine();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "Error: " + e.getMessage();
          }

     }

}
```

Comment: `String.equalsIgnoreCase()`

Comment: Read the documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: Hi     Do you mean for example: s3.equalsIgnoreCase("December") will do it? Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might also consider putting all of your months into an array and doing a simpler comparison:

```
String[] months = {"january", "march", "april", ...};
if (Arrays.asList(months).contains(s3.toLowerCase())
         System.out.println("You will go to Paris");
```

You can construct the array in-line, saving some awful java boilerplate.

Comment: hey this is more neat and less confusing..Thanks for sharing it !

Answer (score 6):

Use `String.equalsIgnoreCase()` , it checks for the equality of the strings case insensitively. [[Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase(java.lang.String))]

Answer (score 3):

To your first question, after the person types in the month, you can type `s2 = s2.toLower()` and then set all of the months in your if-statement to lowercase. As for the other question, sometimes being too concise isn't a good thing. You can't really make your if-statement shorter. You need Java to know exactly what you're checking for equality. Though, as mentioned in another answer, you can also place the months into a set, but make sure to spell them all lowercase if you are going to call `s2.toLower()` on the input string.

Comment: Wow ! genius..For example: Can it convert a weird uppercase and lowercase mix to plain lower case? Like this: SEpTember..I know no one would like to type this way but I think if they just do it by mistake. Thank you!

Comment: @Marie yes, if you call `.toLower()` on that string, it will leave the lowercase letters alone, and change the case of the other letters. "SEpTember" would become "september"

Comment: Thanks alot! This can make it alot easier to do!

Answer (score 3):

For the case insensitivity, you should look at using the [equalsIgnoreCase](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase(java.lang.String)) method provided by the String object.

As for the code style and elegance, I would encapsulate your if statement into a method to improve readability.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s1 = getInput("Enter a month ");
        if(s1.equalsIgnoreCase("February")) {
            System.out.println("It's time to go to the Disneyland !");
            String s2 = getInput("Enter another month: ");
            if(s2.equalsIgnoreCase("February")) {
                System.out.println("You already won a Disneyland ticket! Try       another month.");
                String s3 = getInput("Enter another month: ");
                  if(isValidMonth(s3)) {
                     System.out.println("You will go to Paris");
                  }else {
                     String s4 = getInput("Leave your name and phone number. We will call you back. ");
                     System.out.println("Thanks for visiting! Goodbye !");
                   }    
              }
         }
     }

public static boolean isValidMonth(String s3) {
    if(s3.equalsIgnoreCase("January") || 
                 s3.equalsIgnoreCase("March") || 
                 s3.equalsIgnoreCase("April") || 
                 s3.equalsIgnoreCase("July") || 
                 s3.equalsIgnoreCase("May") || 
                 s3.equalsIgnoreCase("September") || 
                 s3.equalsIgnoreCase("October") || 
                 s3.equalsIgnoreCase("November") || 
                 s3.equalsIgnoreCase("Aguest") || 
                 s3.equalsIgnoreCase("July") || 
                 s3.equalsIgnoreCase("December")) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow I like it! way better !

Comment: Just moves the ugliness elsewhere :)!

Comment: Indeed, there is always going to be ugliness in code, you cant avoid it.  The trick is to simply provide an api which encapsulates the ugliness, and exposes descriptive and readable methods.  Realistically id further encapsulate that behaviour with a validator object, perhaps named MonthValidator, which would contain various methods such as public boolean isDisneyLandMonth(String month) or public boolean isParisMonth(String month).

Comment: Perhaps, but not in this case. There is a legible and easily maintainable solution ready to hand.

Answer (score 1):

```
// magic is in s3.equalsIgnoreCase
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;

    public class Compare {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String s1 = getInput("Enter a month ");
            if(s1.equalsIgnoreCase("February")) {
                System.out.println("It's time to go to the Disneyland !");
                String s2 = getInput("Enter another month: ");
                if(s2.equalsIgnoreCase("February")) {
                    System.out.println("You already won a Disneyland ticket! Try       another month.");
                    String s3 = getInput("Enter another month: ");
                      if(s3.equalsIgnoreCase("January") || 
                         s3.equalsIgnoreCase("March") || 
                         s3.equalsIgnoreCase("April") || 
                         s3.equalsIgnoreCase("July") || 
                         s3.equalsIgnoreCase("May") || 
                         s3.equalsIgnoreCase("September") || 
                         s3.equalsIgnoreCase("October") || 
                         s3.equalsIgnoreCase("November") || 
                         s3.equalsIgnoreCase("Aguest") || 
                         s3.equalsIgnoreCase("July") || 
                         s3.equalsIgnoreCase("December")) {
                         System.out.println("You will go to Paris");
                      }else {
                         String s4 = getInput("Leave your name and phone number. We will call you back. ");
                         System.out.println("Thanks for visiting! Goodbye !");
                       }    
                  }
             }
         }
        private static String getInput(String prompt) {
            BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            System.out.print(prompt);
            System.out.flush();

            try {
                return stdin.readLine();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return "Error: " + e.getMessage();
              }

         }

    }
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks for writing it in details for me!

Answer (score 1):

How about adding all month names to a List (all lower case) and invoking `list.contains(input.toLowerCase())`? This would make your "||" part much more readable.

Comment: equalsIgnorecase is better approach than lowering it and comparing again

Comment: Why a list rather than a set?

Comment: Generally said, I would agree, but this is a case of performance against readability. A minimal larger memory footprint in exchange for a cleaner code. @RealSkeptic: Doesn't really matter, I just wrote an example. But I think a Set would be a little better approach too.

Comment: bratkatoffel Is it possible for you to write within an example from my code maybe a little part so it will be better in visualizing it? Thanks! your idea seams very interesting!

Comment: @bratkartoffel, sorry I stepped on your answer. I didn't see it. Mine is a variation of this Marie.

Comment: @MarieMirbekian Take a look [here](http://pastebin.com/wnMwKQJC). Untested, fast written.

Comment: @Robert Moskal  yes his code looks awesome too but unfortunately I didn't get the more detailed version..I totally understood your code. easy, short and helpful..Thanks !

Comment: @bratkartoffel got your answer .. interesting ! thanks for your effort !

Answer (score 1):

Although my answer is also using the similar approach what others have suggested, but I don't recommend lot of `OR` and `if` conditions. So I suggest below solution which I believe can add more value:

```
package com.test;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Compare {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String s1 = getInput("Enter a month ");
        Month month = Month.valueOf(s1.toUpperCase());
        if (month.isFebruary()) {
            System.out.println("It's time to go to the Disneyland !");
            String s2 = getInput("Enter another month: ");
            month = Month.valueOf(s2.toUpperCase());
            if (month.isFebruary()) {
                System.out
                        .println("You already won a Disneyland ticket! Try       another month.");
                String s3 = getInput("Enter another month: ");

                month = Month.valueOf(s3.toUpperCase());
                if (!month.isFebruary()) {
                    System.out.println("You will go to Paris");
                } else {
                    String s4 = getInput("Leave your name and phone number. We will call you back. ");
                    System.out.println("Thanks for visiting! Goodbye !");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static String getInput(String prompt) {
        BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                System.in));
        System.out.print(prompt);
        System.out.flush();

        try {
            return stdin.readLine();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "Error: " + e.getMessage();
        }

    }

}

enum Month {
    JANUARY, 
    FEBRUARY,
    MARCH,
    APRIL,
    MAY,
    JUNE, 
    JULY,
    AUGUST, 
    SEPTEMBER,
    OCTOBER,
    NOVEMBER,
    DECEMBER;

    public boolean isFebruary() {
        return this == FEBRUARY;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's an ugly use of an enum!

Comment: I have tried to improve it. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: hey this code is very long..Even though i'm looking for the shortest way of doing it.. couldn't think this way! Interesting ! thanks!